# Tkinter frame alignment (grid layout)

Tags: python, tkinter

In Python/Tkinter, I am trying to get a value (integer) from a frame, do a calculation on it and return it as an output. I was able to make it work when using only a master frame and putting everything in that one frame. Now I want to separate it and another operation into their own frames.

My program converts board feet to Lineal feet (frame A) and
Lineal feet to board feet (frame B).

I get errors like: `NameError: global name 'b_entry' is not defined`. I have a feeling I might be doing things like referencing frames (self, master, a_frame, etc.) improperly.

Here's a simple example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.grid()

        b_frame = tk.Frame(master).grid(row=0)
        b_name = tk.Label(b_frame, text='Blah').grid(row=1, columnspan=4)
        b_label = tk.Label(b_frame, text='Label').grid(row=2, column=0)
        b_entry = tk.Entry(b_frame).grid(row=2, column=1)
        b_output = tk.Label(b_frame, text='Output')
        b_output.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)
        b_button = tk.IntVar()
        tk.Button(b_frame, text='calc', command=self.convert).grid(row=4, columnspan=2)

    def convert(self):
        a = int(b_entry.get())
        result = int(a * a)
        b_output.configure(text=result)

root = tk.Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues.

- You should not assign a widget to a variable and pack/grid it on the same line. This causes the variable to have a value of `None`, because that's what `pack` and `grid` return. This will screw up your widget hierarchy because when `b_frame` is None, `tk.Label(b_frame, ...` will make the label a child of the Tk window instead of the Frame.
- If you want a variable to be visible in all of a class' methods, you should assign it as an attribute of `self`.

So you should change lines like

```
b_entry = tk.Entry(b_frame).grid(row = 2, column = 1)
```

To

```
self.b_entry = tk.Entry(b_frame)
self.b_entry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
```

Then you will be able to properly reference the entry in `convert`.

```
a = int(self.b_entry.get())
```

Comment: Ah, ok.  That is interesting.  I was separating the pack/grid code prior to the other day.  I did notice that somethings like trying to do a configure on them made it throw an error. I did find an answer to that issue when searching SO.  Admittedly, I was being a bit lazy by combining them, thinking I would save some typing, but now that you mention it, debugging is a bit more difficult.  Should I put '.self' before every line, or just the lines that need to be called on?

Comment: That worked famous!  I really appreciate the information. I've basically been teaching myself, using SO and Youtube for guidance.  I found that it helps me to reverse-engineer source examples and try to re-implement them into my code.  Most times it works, or at least gives me a jump-off point to try things out to see what works and what doesn't.  I guess sometimes you just need a direct answer to a direct question.  Thanks for your help and time.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: "Should I put 'self' before every line, or just the lines that need to be called on?" You only _have_ to put `self.` before assignments that you want to be accessible in other methods or outside the class entirely. However some people will put them in front of _every_ assignment, perhaps for aesthetic reasons or because they think they might need those values later. It's mostly a matter of personal preference.